# Subconsultas en Laravel no devuelve ningún resultado

Tags: php, subconsultas, laravel-7

Ya estoy desesperada pensando el porque no puedo obtener ningún resultado de las subconsultas sql en LARAVEL.
Este es mi código

```
$Sql= "SELECT cuenta_judicial.IDNRO,demandas2.CI, 
                (SELECT TITULAR from demandado 
                where demandado.CI=demandas2.CI 
                OR (demandado.CI is null 
                AND demandado.IDNRO=demandas2.CI) ) AS TITULAR,
            demandas2.DEMANDA, 
            demandas2.CTA_BANCO, 
            (SELECT sum( mov_cta_judicial.IMPORTE) 
            from mov_cta_judicial 
            where mov_cta_judicial.CTA_JUDICIAL= cuenta_judicial.IDNRO and mov_cta_judicial.TIPO_MOVI='E' 
                AND mov_cta_judicial.TIPO_EXT='C') as CAPITAL,
            (SELECT sum( mov_cta_judicial.IMPORTE) from mov_cta_judicial where mov_cta_judicial.CTA_JUDICIAL= cuenta_judicial.IDNRO and mov_cta_judicial.TIPO_MOVI='E' and mov_cta_judicial.TIPO_EXT='L') as LIQUIDACION ,
            (SELECT sum( mov_cta_judicial.IMPORTE) from mov_cta_judicial where mov_cta_judicial.CTA_JUDICIAL= cuenta_judicial.IDNRO and mov_cta_judicial.TIPO_MOVI='D') AS DEPOSITO 
            from cuenta_judicial,demandas2 
            WHERE demandas2.CTA_BANCO=cuenta_judicial.CTA_JUDICI";

 
 $lista= DB::select($Sql);
```

Esa misma consulta la ejecuto en PHPmyAdmin y devuelve todos los registros. Pero al querer hacerlo en LARAVEL NADA. Alguien sabe porque? que debería hacer?

SIn problemas cuando lo ejecuto así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en laravel nada

Comment: Si le haces un `dd();` a `$lista` que te devuelve en el navegador?

Comment: Me devuelve un array vacio  [] . Es como si no permitiera subconsultas, no sé

Comment: Si la consulta es la misma lo unico que puede estar distinto es que estes conectando a una base de datos distinta o a un host distinto que el de PHPMyAdmin. Revisa si la conexion es la correcta.

Comment: Utilizo la misma base de datos, y localmente. A pesar de eso, se da ese comportamiento inesperado

Comment: Puedes usar DB::statement(" ") para consultas generales.

Comment: @nashvent usar `statment` no es la mejor opción desde el momento que esta destinada para consultas que [no retornan valores](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#running-queries), de hecho en lugar de los datos que espera solo obtendría `true` o `false` pero no los datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes que nada, agradezco mucho los comentarios de los que reaccionaron a mi posteo. Despues de mucho intentar, decidí modificar la sentencia sql ligeramente así, y me ha funcionado:

```
SELECT cuenta_judicial.IDNRO,demandas2.CI, 
(SELECT TITULAR from demandado where demandado.CI=demandas2.CI OR 
(demandado.CI is null AND demandado.IDNRO=demandas2.CI)  limit 1) AS TITULAR,
demandas2.DEMANDA,demandas2.CTA_BANCO, 
(SELECT sum( mov_cta_judicial.IMPORTE) from mov_cta_judicial 
 where mov_cta_judicial.CTA_JUDICIAL= cuenta_judicial.IDNRO and mov_cta_judicial.TIPO_MOVI='E' AND mov_cta_judicial.TIPO_EXT='C' limit 1) as CAPITAL,
(SELECT sum( mov_cta_judicial.IMPORTE) from mov_cta_judicial where mov_cta_judicial.CTA_JUDICIAL= cuenta_judicial.IDNRO and mov_cta_judicial.TIPO_MOVI='E' and mov_cta_judicial.TIPO_EXT='L' limit 1) as LIQUIDACION ,
(SELECT sum( mov_cta_judicial.IMPORTE) from mov_cta_judicial where mov_cta_judicial.CTA_JUDICIAL= cuenta_judicial.IDNRO and mov_cta_judicial.TIPO_MOVI='D' limit 1) AS DEPOSITO from cuenta_judicial,demandas2 WHERE demandas2.CTA_BANCO=cuenta_judicial.CTA_JUDICI
```

La única diferencia con la sentencia inicial es el limit 1, que he agregado a cada subconsulta. Por algún razón Laravel (o cualquier otro factor que no conozco) requiere  limitar explícitamente el resultado de una subconsulta (a pesar que en mi caso, sabía que cada subconsulta retornaba solo un registro y no varios).

Comment: ¿Esta consulta entonces ya funcionó en Laravel?, es decir ¿ya devuelve resultados?

Comment: Si, finalmente, solo tuve que agregar limits a cada subconsulta. Aun no entiendo porque al ejecutarlo sin limits en el gestor phpmyadmin por ejemplo, lanza resultados. Pero para laravel no encuentro explicación del porque me retornaba Nada

Comment: No olvides marcarla como aceptada

Answer (score 1):

Te falta un `return;` cuando en un controlador hacer una consulta, tienes que retornar la consulta.
Ejemplo:

```
$lista= DB::select('SELECT cuenta_judicial.IDNRO,demandas2.CI, 
            (SELECT TITULAR from demandado 
            where demandado.CI=demandas2.CI 
            OR (demandado.CI is null 
            AND demandado.IDNRO=demandas2.CI) ) AS TITULAR,
        demandas2.DEMANDA, 
        demandas2.CTA_BANCO, 
        (SELECT sum( mov_cta_judicial.IMPORTE) 
        from mov_cta_judicial 
        where mov_cta_judicial.CTA_JUDICIAL= cuenta_judicial.IDNRO and mov_cta_judicial.TIPO_MOVI='E' 
            AND mov_cta_judicial.TIPO_EXT="C") as CAPITAL,
        (SELECT sum( mov_cta_judicial.IMPORTE) from mov_cta_judicial where mov_cta_judicial.CTA_JUDICIAL= cuenta_judicial.IDNRO and mov_cta_judicial.TIPO_MOVI="E" and mov_cta_judicial.TIPO_EXT="L") as LIQUIDACION ,
        (SELECT sum( mov_cta_judicial.IMPORTE) from mov_cta_judicial where mov_cta_judicial.CTA_JUDICIAL= cuenta_judicial.IDNRO and mov_cta_judicial.TIPO_MOVI="D") AS DEPOSITO 
        from cuenta_judicial,demandas2 
        WHERE demandas2.CTA_BANCO=cuenta_judicial.CTA_JUDICI');

return response()->json([
    'status' => 'success',
    'data'   => [$lista]
  ]);

#:: O puedes usar
return response($lista);
```

Acabo de resaltar que ya sabes que tienes que importar el DB en el controlador.

```
use DB;
```

Comment: La consulta que le propones va a fallar, tienes un problema de *comillas*

Comment: Tienes razón a cambiarlo.